# Play form binding difficulties - How do I modify a request after getting it in the backend?

Tags: scala, extjs, playframework, extjs4, playframework-2.1

I'm currently trying to connect an Extjs form to a Play! Scala backend.

I have no problem receiving the request, but

`FormName.bindFromRequest.get` returns to me `None` .

I'm able to find the data generated via submitting from Extjs in the POST request in `request.request.body.data` (the first request object is generated by SocialSecure's controller), whereas normally the data bound to the form would be found in `request.request.body.data.elems`

I think Extjs's eschewal of using `<form>` in their inserted HTML is what causes me this problem, but I'd still like to take advantage of Extjs's nice form verification UI.

**Does Play! or Scala have any resources for modifying a request after the server has received it?**

## More info

This is the method my `/requestAudit` cuurently points to after a POST request:

```
def requestAudit = SecuredAction(WithProvider("google")) { // SecureSocial syntax
implicit request => {                              // let's call this line 0'
  println(request.request.body.asFormUrlEncoded)   // let's call this line 1'
  println(request.body.asText)                     // let's call this line 2'
  newAuditForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.error(newAuditForm))
      success => { /*insert the object into my db*/ }
  ) } }
```

### Ext.js request

When I'm debugging in Eclipse with an Ext.js form, the Variables window shows: (click for closeup)
[image] where the form values are located in `request.body.data.key1`, `request.body.data.key2`, etc

### Bootstrap form request

On the other hand, the request for Bootstrap has the values stored in `request.body.data.elems`
[image]

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but why would this behaviour be desired? It sounds like you are trying to perform a man-in-the-middle style attack against your own users.

Comment: I'm having difficulty binding a form generated by Ext.js to the [Play Form object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaForms). I had a working implementation of a form in Bootstrap being bound to my backend, but now that I'm switching to Ext.js... the request body format changed despite having the same fields

Comment: Can you tell us what changed in the request body between your "bootstrap-based" client and your "Ext.js-based" one ?

Comment: So you can see the extjs form data, the problem is that the play bindFromRequest method doesn't support the data structure returned by extjs?  If so why not just transform the extjs data and use the `def bindFromRequest(data: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Form[T]` version of the method?

Comment: @mguillermin updated my question with more information.

Comment: @2manyprojects I'll look into trying to use that. Thanks for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@2manyprojects 's suggestion set me on the right path:

```
newAuditForm.bindFromRequest(
  (request.request.body.asFormUrlEncoded).getOrElse(Map()))
      .fold( ... )
```

worked.

I was still getting form binding errors after changing my code to this, and then I discovered a typo in the `name` property of one of my Ext.js form fields. The name of the field must be the same on both the UI and the Play Form.